# C - counting occurance of letters in a file - Error 139: Segmentation fault

Tags: c

I am writing a program, that counts the occurances of various letters in every line of a text file. I am doing this through a school website, which probably runs a debugger simmilar to Visual Basic. When I try to submit the code I get Error 139: Segmentation fault. 
The program works in my own tests in CodeBlocks, but the site debugger encounters the error above.

The program waits for the user to input the name of the file to check. The contents of the file get saved into array "a". Variable "Riadok" is a line counter and "pismena" is an array that stores letter occurance counts. The program checks each line and prints out a table showing how many times each letter was found in the line.

During submission the site checks for many different types of input and maybe there is something I didn't think of yet. Any advice please? Also, I am a beginner coder so any advice about the code itself and improvement is welcome.

This is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
int main(){
 int riadok=1, pismena[26],i;
 char a[100],c='0';
 FILE *fr;

 for (i=0;i<=25;i++) pismena[i]=0;
 scanf("%s",a);
 fr= fopen(a, "r");
 printf("    A  B  C  D  E  F  G  H  I  J  K  L  M  N  O  P  Q  R  S  T  U  V  W  X  Y  Z\n");
 while ((c=getc(fr))!=EOF){
  if(c!='\n') {
    c=toupper(c); 
    pismena[c-'A']++; 
  } 
  else if(c=='\n') {
    printf("%2d",riadok); 
    riadok++;
    for (i=0;i<=25;i++){
      printf(" %2d",pismena[i]);
      pismena[i]=0;
      c='0' ;
    }
    printf("\n");
   }
 } 
 printf("%2d",riadok); 
 riadok++;
 for (i=0;i<=25;i++){
   printf(" %2d",pismena[i]);
   pismena[i]=0;
 }
 printf("\n");
 fclose(fr);
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: `Segmentation fault` is a runtime error.

Comment: @KlasLindbäck Sorry not a native speaker- does runtime error mean it ran for too long?

Comment: In your `while ((c-getc(fr))!=EOF)` loop how do you know that you read in a value which is an alphabetic character? The code in the loop assumes that it must be, or you will access outside the bounds of `pismena[]`. For example, if `c` is `\n` it will fail.

Comment: @user3023333 It means that the program crashes when run (in this case probably due to input that contains characters outside A-Z).

Comment: Change `char c='0';` to `int c;`. This is very important, because the `getc` function actually returns an int, and it can be outside the range of `char`.

Comment: Both of your `c='0'` lines have no effect as you only ever check `c` after doing `c=getc(fr)` .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line can cause segmentation fault if `c` is anything other than a letter:

```
pismena[c-'A']++;
```

One way to fix it:

```
if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z') {
    pismena[c-'A']++; 
}
```

Comment: More portably, `if ( c - 'A' >= 0 && c - 'A' < 26 )`

Comment: And more standards compliant: [`isupper`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/isupper).

Comment: Oh ok thanks that worked like charm :) Such an obvious mistake too... Now the site says the output is wrong, but Ill solve that somehow, its probably extra spaces or something like that. Thanks again

Comment: @Matt & Joachim I chose my approach because of it's readability. Joachims approach will fail in a locale with more than 26 letters (for example Sweden or Germany).

Comment: @KlasLindbäck I think you mean that Matt's will fail in those locales. the library isalpha and isupper functions are locale specific (and written with table lookups to account for the really strange locales)

Comment: @Steve Depends on what you mean with fail. I was referring to writing outside the buffer (for example `'Ö' - 'A'` is greater than 25, and 'Ö' is upper in a swedish locale). I'm assuming that the program only needs to handle letters A-Z regardless of the locale. Otherwise the program would need a major overhaul.

Comment: @KlasLindbäck you're completely right. My interpretation of fail was the exact opposite.

Answer (score 1):

You should test if `c` is between 'A' and 'Z' inclusive before you use `[c-'A']` index to your array.